# Alooper_addFd data parameter

Tags: android, native-code, android-looper

I am not sure how this function works. This is prototype:

```
int ALooper_addFd(ALooper*looper, int fd, int ident, int events, ALooper_callbackFunc callback, void *data);
```

What is this 'data' pointer? If callback is not NULL, 'data' should be custom data passed to callback. But, if callback is NULL, what is 'data' parameter used for? Or it have to be NULL also, in that case?

Is there any detailed documentation about this? Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pointer to arbitrary data that you can set if you need it in your application.

Apart from being sent as an argument to the callback, the `data` pointer will also be written to the memory referenced by the `outData` parameter when you call `ALooper_pollAll` or `ALooper_pollOnce`.

You can see the Android Native App Glue as an example. In this case, the `data` points to an `android_poll_source` structure defined by the glue, and to make the glue translate the commands from the looper's file descriptor into input and `APP_CMD` events, you must call the `process` function in `(android_poll_source *)data` when you receive an event from the looper:

```
int ident, events;
struct android_poll_source *source; // source is the data here
while ((ident = ALooper_pollAll(0, NULL, &events, (void **)(&source))) >= 0) {
    if (source) {
        source->process(source->app, source);
    }
}
```